# Why do I have an array with data about the exchange rate in the middle of an asynchronous function , but outside of it I have an empty array? - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm new to programming and I can't solve this problem for 5 days.

I'm trying to get the rate of a specific currency between 1 and 50000 from the API. And I manage to get the correct currency rate in the middle of the getCurrenciesValues ​​async function, but outside the function I get an empty array. I already tried to transfer data from an asynchronous function to an empty array outside the function in different ways. Used a **for loop**, tried using **async/wait**, also **.then()** and **.push** to send data to an array outside of the async function. Sometimes the console, which was outside the asynchronous function, showed me an array with data, but when using **JSON.stringify**, it indicated that the array is actually empty. This is what my code looks like

```
const defaultData = [
{ value: 1 }, { value: 5 }, { value: 10 },
{ value: 25 }, { value: 50 }, { value: 100 },
{ value: 500 }, { value: 1000 }, { value: 5000 },
{ value: 10000 }, { value: 50000 }];

function CurrencyTable({ choiceFrom, choiceTo, labelFrom, labelTo }
: IProps) {

const currenciesValues: any[] = [];

useEffect(() => {
    getCurrenciesValues();
}, [choiceFrom, choiceTo])

async function getCurrenciesValues () {
    const promise = await Promise.all(defaultData.map(async (number) => {
        const { result } = await fetchFromAPI(`convert?from=${choiceFrom}&to=${choiceTo}&amount=${number.value}`);
        return result
    }))
    currenciesValues.push(promise);
    console.log("Inside currenciesValues", currenciesValues);
}

console.log("Outside currenciesValues", currenciesValues);
```

and this is the response I get in the console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX7LZ.png)

If necessary, I will also attach a wire to this repository : https://github.com/VladyslavMazurets/currency_converter/blob/main/src/components/CurrencyTable.tsx

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Questions like this are very common on Stack Overflow. You're logging the "Outside currenciesValues" _before the call to `getCurrenciesValues` completes_. You need to capture the Promise returned by `getCurrenciesValues()` and await it before your final logging statement (or put the final logging statement in a `.then()` call off of it).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend if you want to maintain a value in a React component to use state. So you could change what you have to something like this

```
const defaultData = [
{ value: 1 }, { value: 5 }, { value: 10 },
{ value: 25 }, { value: 50 }, { value: 100 },
{ value: 500 }, { value: 1000 }, { value: 5000 },
{ value: 10000 }, { value: 50000 }];

function CurrencyTable({ choiceFrom, choiceTo, labelFrom, labelTo }
: IProps) {

const [currenciesValues, setCurrenciesValues] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    getCurrenciesValues();
}, [choiceFrom, choiceTo])

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Outside currenciesValues", currenciesValues);
}, [currenciesValues])

async function getCurrenciesValues () {
    const promise = await Promise.all(defaultData.map(async (number) => {
        const { result } = await fetchFromAPI(`convert?from=${choiceFrom}&to=${choiceTo}&amount=${number.value}`);
        return result
    }))
    setCurrenciesValues([...currencyValues, promise]);
    console.log("Inside currenciesValues", currenciesValues);
}

console.log("Outside currenciesValues", currenciesValues);
```

And then move your console log inside a useEffect

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped me and solved a problem that I could not solve for a long time. Thank you again